# Make simple array from database array return is not a subtype of type 'List<UserWeightsData>' error

Tags: flutter

i can successful get data from database and i try to make simple `LineChart` from that,

when i try to make simple array of data, o don't get any error, but when i make that with `for` statement i get this error:

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<UserWeightsData>'
```

for example:

```
class UserWeightsData {
  int weightNum;
  int weightValue;

  UserWeightsData(this.weightNum, this.weightValue);
}

...
List<charts.Series<UserWeightsData, int>> _seriesWeightsLineData;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _seriesWeightsLineData = List<charts.Series<UserWeightsData, int>>();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
     body: _buildLineChart(context),
  );
}
```

now in this method: when i uncomment this part of code

```
var data = [
    UserWeightsData(0,20),
    UserWeightsData(1,24),
    UserWeightsData(2,25),
    UserWeightsData(3,40),
];
```

and commenting `for` statement, my code work fine without any problem. in that i can't make this array with `for` statement

`for` statement result:

[image]

as you can see `for` work fine and can make this array, but in this part of code as `_seriesWeightsLineData.add(charts.Series(` i get error

```
StreamBuilder<List<UserWeightTableData>> _buildLineChart(BuildContext context) {
  final database = Provider.of<UserWeightTableDao>(context);
  return StreamBuilder<List<UserWeightTableData>>(
    stream: database.streamStoredUserWeights(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      final List<UserWeightTableData> weightsList = snapshot.data ?? List();
      if(weightsList.isEmpty){
        return Container(child:Text('no data'));
      }else{
        var data = [];

        for (int o = 0; o < weightsList.length; o++) {
          data.add(UserWeightsData(o, weightsList[o].weight));
        }

        /*var data = [
            UserWeightsData(0,20),
            UserWeightsData(1,24),
            UserWeightsData(2,25),
            UserWeightsData(3,40),
        ];*/

        _seriesWeightsLineData.add(charts.Series(
          data: data,
          domainFn: (UserWeightsData weight, _) => weight.weightNum,
          measureFn: (UserWeightsData weight, _) => weight.weightValue,
          colorFn: (UserWeightsData weight, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color(0xff990099)),
          id: 'weights',
          labelAccessorFn: (UserWeightsData row, _) => '${row.weightValue}',
        ));

        return Container(
          height: 200.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: charts.LineChart(
            _seriesWeightsLineData,
            defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(includeArea: true, stacked: true),
            animate: true,
            animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            behaviors: [new charts.PanAndZoomBehavior()],
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `data`'s list a type when you create it - otherwise it becomes a list of anything (`List<dynamic>`).

```
var data = <UserWeightsData>[];
```

Now it's a `List<UserWeightsData>`.